# Hitting Enter on TextBox Submits

Tags: button, user-controls, textbox, submit

I am working on a user control (ascx) with an asp TextBox control.
Whenever I press the enter key on the TextBox, the user control automatically submits it.
I do not want that to happen. I want to disable automatic submit on press of the enter key on any other control aside from the Submit Button.

Please note that I do not use any HTML controls aside from Table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put javascript code and disable `Enter` Key event ...

```
<div onkeypress="return noenter(event)">
```

javascript code :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function noenter(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
        return key !== 13; 
    }
</script>
```